# R plot for multiple files in folder

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, plot, readxl

By using R programming I want to read files in folder. perform some operations on it, plot and save as csv1.

Read next file, perform same operations, plot and save the new modified dataframe in csv1 with rbind function. Remember I want 1 plot from all files I read in for loop and save plot as pdf.

Right now i am using following code but my system crash due to shortage of RAM

```
all_paths <-
  list.files(path = "/work/newplots",
             pattern = "*.*",
             full.names = TRUE)

all_filenames <- all_paths %>%
  basename() %>%
  as.list()

all_content <-
  all_paths %>%
  lapply(read.table,
         header = TRUE,
         skip=60,
         sep=',',
         encoding = "UTF-8")


file <- data.frame()


for (i in 1:length(all_filenames)) {

    all_lists <- mapply(c, all_content, i, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

    data <- rbindlist(all_lists, fill = T)

    names(data)[1] <- "File.Path"

    x1 <- data %>% select(V1) %>% unique()
    data <- data %>% data.frame(str_split_fixed(data$File.Path, " ", 23))%>% select(-c(File.Path))%>% filter(X1=='Interactions')

    data<- cbind(x1,data)

    data <- data %>% select(-c(2)) %>%select(V1,X2)

    data$X2 <-as.numeric(data$X2) 

   
    file <- write.table(data,"/work/con1_10.csv",row.names = FALSE)
    file <- append(file,data)
    p<-plot(data$X2, xlab="Cycle number",ylab="Interactions",type = "p")
    print(p)
    Z<- (2*data$X2)/20006
    px<-plot(Z, xlab="Cycle number", ylab="Z")
    print(px)

}
```

Comment: I think you can use the « pdf » function of the grDevices packages.  You can use something like pdf("my_Plot.pdf"); plot(my_Data); dev.off()

Comment: how can I save the data as csv alongwith it

Comment: Look at the `write.csv` or `write.csv2` function